# Exercise 25 section 4.3 Dummit & Foote

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

[image]

Hello. I would appreciate any guidance on my solution for the above exercise (only the part that says that every element of G is conjugate to some element of H):

Let A $\in Gl_2(\mathbb{C})$ and suppose $v_1, v_2$ is a basis of the complex vector space. Since every operator over $\mathbb{C}$ has an upper triangular matrix (name it S) with respect to some basis ($u_1, u_2$) of the complex vector space, let B be the change of basis matrix that changes $u_1,u_2$ coordinates into $v_1,v_2$ coordinates. The change of basis matrix is an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{C}$), hence $A = B^{-1}SB$ where $S \in H$.

Is this correct?

Comment: That is what the question asks, assuming you know to prove the quoted result

Comment: You mean the fact that every operator over C has an upper triangular matrix?

Comment: Correct, extra spaces

Comment: Oh okay. That is fine. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Schur Decomposition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), which states

> Every matrix in $ A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ can be written as $QTQ^{-1}$ where $T$ is upper triangular and $Q$ is unitary.

and is itself a generalization of the [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem), which states

> Every hermitian matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ can be written as $QDQ^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal and $Q$ is unitary.

So if you are allowed to quote Schur Decomposition Theorem, then you could simply say that if  $A \in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$, we can write $A = QTQ^{-1}$, and $T$ must be invertible because $A$ is invertible, so the product of the elements on the diagonal of $T$ is non-zero, so $T$ is in your subgroup $H$.

However, since you are probably not allowed to quote this theorem directly, I wrote a proof for your exercise below which is just adapting the proof of the Schur Decomposition Theorem for invertible, $2 \times 2$ matrices. (The proof of the Schur Decomposition Theorem is itself similar to the proof of the Spectral Theorem.)

---

Suppose $A \in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Let $v_1$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, which is non-zero since $A$ is invertible. Let $v_2$ be any vector that is not a multiple of $v_1$. Let $V$ be the $2 \times 2$ matrix with columns $v_1, v_2$, and expand $Av_2 = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2.$ To be explicit,
$$V = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Our choice of $v_2$ ensures that $V$ is invertible. We have
$$AV = A \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda v_1 & c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & c_1\\
0 & c_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore

$$A = V\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & c_1\\
0 & c_2 \end{bmatrix}V^{-1}.$$
Now, $c_2$ cannot be $0$ because that would imply that $A$ is singular. Therefore we have shown that $A$ is conjugate to an element of $H$.